# Стихотворение Ю. Друниной "Зине"

Tags: литература

О чем скучает героиня стихотворения Ю. Друниной "Зине"?

Comment: @бобир В чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос задан некорректно. Фамилия поэтессы - Друнина.

Comment: Просто кое-кто ленится сам делать домашние задания, а о понятии "русский язык" слышал пару раз в жизни, как и о том, что названия стихотоворений пишутся в кавычках.

Answer (score 1):

Скучает? Гм-гм...

Не "Зине", а "Зинка".

1.Мы легли у разбитой ели,
Ждем, когда же начнет светлеть.
Под шинелью вдвоем теплее
На продрогшей, сырой земле.

- Знаешь, Юлька, я  против грусти,
  Но сегодня она не в счет.
  Дома, в яблочном захолустье,
  Мама, мамка моя живет.

У тебя есть друзья, любимый.
У меня  лишь она одна.
Пахнет в хате квашней и дымом,
За порогом бурлит весна.

Старой кажется: каждый кустик
Беспокойную дочку ждет
Знаешь, Юлька, я  против грусти,
Но сегодня она  не в счет.

Отогрелись мы еле-еле,
Вдруг приказ: «Выступать вперед!»
Снова рядом в сырой шинели
Светлокосый солдат идет.

1. С каждым днем становилось горше.
   Шли без митингов и замен.
   В окруженье попал под Оршей
   Наш потрепанный батальон.

Зинка нас повела в атаку.
Мы пробились по черной ржи,
По воронкам и буеракам,
Через смертные рубежи.

Мы не ждали посмертной славы,
Мы со славой хотели жить.
Почему же в бинтах кровавых
Светлокосый солдат лежит

Ее тело своей шинелью
Укрывала я, зубы сжав.
Белорусские хаты пели
О рязанских глухих садах.

1. Знаешь, Зинка, я  против грусти,
   Но сегодня она не в счет.
   Дома, в яблочном захолустье
   Мама, мамка твоя живет.

У меня есть друзья, любимый
У нее ты была одна.
Пахнет в хате квашней и дымом,
За порогом бурлит весна.

И старушка в цветастом платье
У иконы свечу зажгла
Я не знаю, как написать ей,
Чтоб она тебя не ждала.